# How to SQL Pass-through in SAS, create view or table

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I am trying to create a View on the database through SAS, SQL passthrough the following way

```
PROC sql; 
CONNECT TO odbc AS myuser(dsn=galaxy);              
EXECUTE(
CREATE VIEW DB.SCHEM.table AS
    SELECT * FROM connection to myuser;
    (SELECT * FROM DB.SCHEM.table2)
)by myuser;
QUIT;
```

Howeever, I get the following errors

> ERROR: CLI prepare error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
>   11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect
>          syntax near the keyword 'select'. : [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>          Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Why are you doing your second select statement ?

Comment: I am trying to create a view in the database by pass through., even if I have it like `code` execute(
            create View DB.SCHEM.table as select * from DB.SCHEMA.table2 `code` it gives an error that it doesnt allow specifying the database name as a prefix.

Comment: Yes, but why two select statement ? Without UNION ?

Comment: I am trying to create a view in the database by pass through., even if I have it like `code` execute( create View DB.SCHEM.table as select * from DB.SCHEMA.table2 `code` it gives an error that it doesnt allow specifying the database name as a prefix.

Comment: What is the simple way to create a table or View from another table on the database via Pass-through?

Comment: The `by myuser` clause performs the connection for the `EXECUTE` statement. You do not need to deal with connections inside the EXECUTE.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extraneous `SELECT * FROM connection to myuser;` inside the EXECUTE.  The code inside `EXECUTE` is submitted directly to SQL server, and your extraneous code is invalid.

Here is the SAS pass-through corrected.  I would advise against using `table` as part of view name.  Note: You will see an error message if your SQL Server credentials do not have the data base grants needed to create a view.

```
EXECUTE(
  CREATE VIEW DB.SCHEM.table AS
  SELECT * FROM DB.SCHEM.table2
) by myuser ;
```

From [SQL Server docs for CREATE VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> ```
> CREATE [ OR ALTER ] VIEW [ schema_name . ] view_name [ (column [ ,...n ] ) ]   
> [ WITH <view_attribute> [ ,...n ] ]   
> AS select_statement   
> [ WITH CHECK OPTION ]   
> [ ; ]
> ```